# Not getting value from data base under select tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My select tag is

```
<%= f.select(:item,{selected: :item},{}, { :class => 'form-control item' }) %>
```

I am inserting the data base on selection of other field with the help of JS and it works fine. But when I open the link to edit my data I am get 
`selected` as the value in the option of select tag instead of value. Data is present in the database but why rails is not getting it up in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proper usage of select tag in Rails

```
<%= f.select :item, options_for_select(@items, f.object.item), {:include_blank => '--Select Item--'}, { :class => 'form-control item' } %>
```

where @items is a array like:

```
@items = [['One',1], ['Two',2], ['Three',3]]
```

Comment: Still I am not getting the value from the database insted Value shown as [--Select Item--]

Comment: Provide your @items array?

Comment: I have already given it I need to fetch the data from database only